# Laravel - Integrity contraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been struggling with the problem for quite some time now and I'm getting a little bit desperate for a solution because I'm not that great at problem-solving. Anyway, I am trying to seed my database, And I followed a tutorial of Jeffrey from Laracasts in his forum series where he adds a slug to a thread. Well, I'm trying to do the same to my posts but when I seed my database I get the error stated in the title, What is causing this?

I got my migration here:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->Unsignedinteger('user_id');
        $table->Unsignedinteger('channel_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->longText('text');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to do with my seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $title = $faker->sentence;

    foreach(range(1, 30) as $index) {
        DB::table('posts')->insert([
            'user_id' => rand(1, 50),
            'channel_id' => rand(1,14),
            'title' => $faker->sentence,
            'slug' => str_slug($title),
            'text' => $faker->paragraph,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);

    }
}
```

And for the sake of keeping this question short, I'll show the full error code in a picture which is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pfeh.jpg

But the problem is, In my migration, I set the slug to be unique and In my seed, I assigned the title to be equal to the slug, And that cannot be done because slug is unique, But in the tutorial, he has done the same, How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Link to tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    foreach(range(1, 30) as $index) {

      $title = $faker->sentence;

      DB::table('posts')->insert([
          'user_id' => rand(1, 50),
          'channel_id' => rand(1,14),
          'title' => $faker->sentence,
          'slug' => str_slug($title),
          'text' => $faker->paragraph,
          'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
          'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
      ]);

    }

}
```

Comment: [Code-only answers are considered low-quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).  Adding an explanation about what you've done, and why, will greatly increase the quality of your answer.  What does your code do that OP's does not?  Why do you think it will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$title` is only set 1x, outside your loop.  So you are trying to create 30 records with the same slug, which will of course fail if they need to be unique.  Shift the `title` and `slug` creation into your loop to make sure they are new and unique with each iteration:

```
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    foreach(range(1, 30) as $index) {

        $title = $faker->sentence;
        $slug = str_slug($title);

        DB::table('posts')->insert([
            'user_id' => rand(1, 50),
            'channel_id' => rand(1,14),
            'title' => $title,
            'slug' => $slug,
            'text' => $faker->paragraph,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos in the migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); // here
        $table->unsignedInteger('channel_id'); // and here
        $table->string('title');
        $table->longText('text');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then I suggest you to use the [Model Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#writing-factories) for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the row with duplicate id in the test -database with softDelete on (i.e. deleted_at set), which caused this error. In my case, I added Model::withTrashed()->where() to get also the soft deleted rows.